# Going through my entire $_SESSION array and removing null variables

Tags: php

I've been doing some tests with $_SESSION variables and that left a lot of them set to NULL, but still existing. I can remove them one-by-one, but how can I just loop through the $_SESSION array and remove NULL variables quickly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will remove `NULL` values, but not other empty or `FALSE`. Easily modified if you also want rid of `FALSE` vals and empty strings, etc.

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$var)
{
  if ($var === NULL) unset($_SESSION[$key]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`array_filter`](http://php.net/array_filter) with a callback function that uses [`is_null`](http://php.net/is_null):

```
$output = array_filter($input, function($val) { return !is_null($val); });
```

Comment: `$output = array_filter($input, 'count');` will have (nearly) the same effect.

Answer (score 3):

```
$_SESSION = array_filter($_SESSION, 'count');
```

Will have the effect of removing all `NULL` values (since `count()` returns `0` for `NULL`) and also any countable (either an array or an object) that has 0 elements, from the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php):

> Returns the number of elements in var,
>   which is typically an array, since
>   anything else will have one element.
>
> If var is not an array or an object
>   with implemented Countable interface,
>   1 will be returned. **There is one
>   exception, if var is NULL, 0 will be
>   returned.**

Since `0` evaluates to false in a boolean context there is no need to implement any custom function.

Answer (score 1):

`$_SESSION = array_filter($_SESSION);`

This will remove any "falsy" values from the session array, including `null`.

Answer (score 1):

That should do it:

```
foreach ($_SESSION as $key => $value)
{
    if ($value === NULL)
        unset($_SESSION[$key];
}
```

P.S. array_filter will remove anything equal to "false". You should provide your own callback function or use this example if you need to remove only NULL-values and keep empty strings or zeros.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION as $key => $value){
   if(empty($value) || is_null($value)){
       unset($_SESSION[$key]);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are "deleting" `$_SESSION` elements by setting value to NULL, you are doing it wrong. To unset array element you should use 
[`unset`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) 
on `$_SESSION` element.

```
# Wrong
$_SESSION['foo'] = NULL;

#Good
unset($_SESSION['foo']);
```